# how the Image.ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize() command works?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I need to use this command to select the text with the biggest font size but after countless tries nothing works

I've tried:
`Image.ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize(text)` {text is a variable for the text it scans through}

> [ERROR]: TypeError: getsize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

`Image.ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize(text = 'Lorem Ipsum')`

> [ERROR]: TypeError: getsize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

`Image.ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize(self, text = 'Lorem Ipsum')`

> [ERROR]: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

I don't quite understand what self is supposed to do/mean.

Side Note: If the code is supposed to look through text and find the biggest font size, why do I have to choose a word whose font size it should determine, shouldn't it do that for the whole passage?

Here is my code in its entirety:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont

image = Image.open('screenshot - copy.bmp') 

fontget = ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize(text = 'food')
print(fontget)
```

What I want it to do is scan through a passage and return different font sizes.
From there I will make it print the text with the biggest font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ERROR]: TypeError: getsize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

The previous error means that you called an instance method on a class, not an *instance* of a class. You have to instantiate the `ImageFont` class by loading a font first.

```
>>> from PIL import ImageFont
>>> font = ImageFont.load_default()
>>> font.getsize('hello world')
(66, 11)
```

> Side Note: If the code is supposed to look through text and find the biggest font size, why do I have to choose a word whose font size it should determine, shouldn't it do that for the whole passage?

This is not what `getsize()` does. It returns the size of text that `PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text()` would draw in the selected font.

```
>>> font.getsize('h')
(6, 11)
>>> font.getsize('hello')
(30, 11)
>>> font.getsize('hello hello this is long text and you can see x gets bigger because the text gets wider')
(522, 11)
```

Comment: Oh, I see now. Not quite what I hoped that command would do but thanks so much for explaining lol!

Answer (score 0):

**now in pillow 10 you can use**

Instead of `ImageFont.FreeTypeFont(fontfile, size=55, encoding="unic")` and `getsize(string)`

use `ImageFont.truetype(fontfile, size=55, encoding="unic")` and `getlength(string)`